# How to work Cache of media/catalog/product/cache in Magento

Tags: image, caching, magento

i want to know how to work the cache of media/catalog/product/cache i don´t know how made the directory structure. 
My example is

```
media\catalog\product\cache

  \1\small_image\120x120\9df78dab3d52sd08dse5fw8d27w36e95

      a\
      b\
      d\
      ...
```

i don´t understand how to take the number 1 in cache\
next how to take the hash key 9df78dab3d52sd08dse5fw8d27w36e95
and many times in stead of higthxweith(directory) take numberx(directory)
I need to know all because i want to made a external CDN and liberate to resize images in my machine.
Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to know more about that hash key, I believe it is created in the Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image class, at the bottom of the setBaseFile function, it basically takes properties of the image, implodes them together and creates a hash.

```
    // add misk params as a hash
    $miscParams = array(
            ($this->_keepAspectRatio  ? '' : 'non') . 'proportional',
            ($this->_keepFrame        ? '' : 'no')  . 'frame',
            ($this->_keepTransparency ? '' : 'no')  . 'transparency',
            ($this->_constrainOnly ? 'do' : 'not')  . 'constrainonly',
            $this->_rgbToString($this->_backgroundColor),
            'angle' . $this->_angle,
            'quality' . $this->_quality
    );

    // if has watermark add watermark params to hash
    if ($this->getWatermarkFile()) {
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkFile();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkImageOpacity();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkPosition();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkWidth();
        $miscParams[] = $this->getWatermarkHeigth();
    }
```

If you need to generate the hash yourself you can use the same steps. Obviously HASH'ing is a one way process, so it is impossible to take the value and find out the image properties.

Comment: Thanks, in this method also find the 1(number). This made reference to Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()

Comment: the number x number made reference to {$this->_width}x{$this->_height} in the same method