# Magento Image Cache URL - Wrong Cache Key

Tags: magento, caching, image-caching

For some reason my Magento is trying to return the cache key 040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f on the frontend yet it should be looking for 9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95.

I don't know what is going wrong here. I entirely emptied the cache and reindexed. It is creating the new image cache as I go to pages. It also creates them with one additional 'size' directory.

WRONG FRONTEND: http://mysite.com/catalog/product/cache/1/image/**040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f**/d/i/dio156c.jpg

CORRECT: http://mysite.com/catalog/product/cache/1/image/**265x265/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95**/d/idio156c.jpg

Is there anything I can do to force it to use the correct url?

Comment: I suspect this question lacks the context needed for anyone to come up with an answer.

Comment: Upon looking at it further, it is working on the main images but for some reason a template extension (Cloud Zoom) is trying to use a different image url for 'popups'. When I try to click on the image for the zoom effect it is using the wrong cache-key in the url and therefore displays a 404.  I guess to be more specific in my question, If Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image controls the cache url, why would there be two different URL options for the same image? It was working and now its not, so I'm not sure how I 'broke' it.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase — this is a programming site and you didn't include a single line of code.

Comment: I have found the solution. I was not really understanding how the hash was being built: I was not passing it a proper width parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894778/how-to-work-cache-of-media-catalog-product-cache-in-magento